# How to override Yii2 TimestampBehavior?

Tags: yii2

So I've this function in my Model.

```
public function behaviors() {

    return [
        TimestampBehavior::className(),
    ];
}
```

`created_at` and `updated_at` works as expected.

But I need to pass in a certain time for the `updated_at` whenever the data is updated.

How do I do that? Can't seem to find any resources on that.

Answer (score -1):

Just use [`preserveNonEmptyValues`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-attributebehavior#$preserveNonEmptyValues-detail) property (available since version 2.0.13):

```
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'preserveNonEmptyValues' => true,
        ]
    ];
}
```

Comment: Author of the question write in comment: "I need to pass my own $time into the behaviour somehow". In this case my answer is correct.